# React table Re-render performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table that displays around 200 rows / 8 columns (one field displays subrows). It's parent component has 2 radio buttons that filter the table data in such a way that there is no overlapping data in the 2 subsets. The problem I am having is that whenever the table is re-rendered it hangs for a couple seconds. Is there any way I can make this perform better or do I need to look into something such as react-virtualized? Thanks

```
var TableList = function (props) {
    var data = props.data;
    var headers = Object.keys(data[0]);

    return (
        React.DOM.table({ className: 'u-full-width' },
            React.DOM.thead(null,
                React.DOM.tr(null,
                    headers.map(function (header, i) {
                        return React.DOM.th({ key: i }, header);
                    })
                )
            ),
            React.DOM.tbody(null,
                data.map(function (record, i) {
                    var cols = headers.map(function (header, i) {
                        if (header === "expand1" || header === "expand2") {
                            return React.DOM.td({ key: i },
                                record[header].map(function (obj, i) {
                                    return (
                                        React.DOM.div({ className: 'row', key: i },
                                            React.DOM.div({ className: 'two columns', style: { textAlign: 'left' } }, 'item: ' + i ),
                                            React.DOM.div({ className: 'eight columns', style: { textAlign: 'center' } }, obj.name),
                                            React.DOM.div({ className: 'two columns', style: { textAlign: 'right' } }, '(' + obj.percent ' %)')
                                        )
                                    );
                                })
                            );
                        }
                        return React.DOM.td({ key: i }, record[header] || "-");
                    });
                    return React.DOM.tr({ key: i }, cols);
                })
            )
        )
    )
};
```

Comment: Tables are extremely slow in the browser; every time you even update a single property of a table, it has to recalculate and repaint the entire table layout; this is known as "layout thrashing". If you want something more performant, don't use tables.

Comment: A followup to @ndugger 's point - why are you using tables?  If it's to tabulate data - yeah, that's gotta be a table, but if you're going for layouts you should probably stick to well styled `div`s.

Comment: I am not using the table for layout. I am displaying the data related to a chart in another component.